# difference between move_uploaded_file AND is_uploaded_file

Tags: php

When uploading a file from a php form using

```
<input name="xxx" type="file">
```

is it necessary to use the php function **is_uploaded_file** to check if it was uploaded via PHP's HTTP POST upload mechanism?

I've read all there is to read about that function and i don't see the use? Am i wrong?

in the php documentation it says

> Returns TRUE if the file named by filename was uploaded via HTTP POST. This is useful to help ensure that a malicious user hasn't tried to trick the script into working on files upon which it should not be working

but, the main function to upload the file **move_uploaded_file** also checks if it's a valid file

> This function checks to ensure that the file designated by filename is a valid upload file (meaning that it was uploaded via PHP's HTTP POST upload mechanism). If the file is valid, it will be moved to the filename given by destination.

so, my question is the following:

Is it really necessary to use **is_upload_file** if, presumably, **move_uploaded_file** already does the checking for malicious content ?

```
// if artwork file upload correctly, continue!
if ($_FILES['artwork']['error'][0] == 0) {

    // check if the artwork file was uploaded via HTTP POST to prevent a malicious attack
    if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['artwork']['tmp_name'][0])) {

       // move files
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

`move_uploaded_file` will return an ambiguous `false`, meaning you don't know whether or not the move was successful, or the file was valid.

In the case of a web application the user would not know what went wrong (nor would the developer). I would therefore suggest first checking the validity of the file and logging/outputting the appropriate error message before trying to move the file.

Comment: Great answer, never thought if it like this. :-)

Comment: thanks. when you say to check the validity prior to moving... what do you mean? the MIME type/ the size? or a function that does it ?

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use **is_uploaded_file** when using **move_uploaded_file**.

**is_uploaded_file** is only needed if you want to access the uploaded temp-file directly (without moving it)

Comment: What if I wanted to read the uploaded file directly, could I call `is_uploaded_file()` and then, say, directly read the file into memory, perform some processing / validation, and then write it to disk elsewhere?